# Double integration of trig function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The function I am trying to integrate is:

$$\int_0^{12}\int_{y/4}^3 \sin(x^2)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x$$

I am having trouble finding out where to start. I have tried to just go ahead and integrate, but then I would have to deal with calculating cosine of $9$ and $\left(\frac{y}{4}\right)^3$. I thought about changing the order of integration, but how would you do that considering the inner bound is a function of $x$?

I would greatly appreciate some help to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Draw a picture of your region. That will help you determine the bounds for your change of variable. You should find swictching the order gives $$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{4x} \sin(x^{2}) dydx$$ Also, I think your integration should go $dxdy$ not $dydx$ as you have it now.

Comment: You can't just "go ahead in integrate"  $\int \sin (x^2) dx$ does not integrate into elemetary functions.  But if you change the order of integration, then a substitution will make itself available to you such that you will have something that is integrable.

Comment: @Mattos Thank you for your concise explanation. I also thought it would work only as dxdy, not dydx. I'm assuming my professor made a typo on the worksheet.

Comment: @user78100 The inner integral as you have it is asking you to integrate a function with bounds in $y$ with respect to $y$, so either there is a typo or the professor is doing something I've never heard of.

Comment: I second @Mattos first comment. That’s why I prefer the notation $$\int_0^{12}\mathrm{d}y\int_{y/4}^3\mathrm{d}x\sin x^2$$

Comment: Do you mean $\,\displaystyle \int_0^{12} \left(\int_{y/4}^3 \sin(x^2) dx\right) dy\,$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{12}\left( \int_{y/4}^{3}\sin (x^2)dx\right)dy\\&=\int_0^3dx\int_0^{4x} \sin(x^2)dy\\&=\int_0^3\sin(x^2)4xdx \\
&= 2\int_0^3\sin(x^2)d(x^2)\\&=2\int_0^9\sin udu \\&=2(1-\cos 9) 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: +1 nice.............

Comment: @Bach How does the change of limits in the first step (from $\int_{0}^{12} \int_{y/4}^{3}$ to $\int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{4x}$) work? Can't quite see it.